# PM2 cluster mode run multiple redis pub/sub clients

Tags: node.js, redis, pm2

I try to use PM2 cluster mode to run multiple redis pub/sub clients. However, the clients can not connect successfully. If I just use PM2 fork mode, the redis pub/sub clients works well.

I tried to find the solution, but I can'f find any useful information. Any person encountered the same situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot connect successfully"? Do you get an error message? What commands did you run to get to this point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.